# How to exclude Facebook Pixel and Google Analytics from firing on one Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, facebook-pixel

I'm trying to setup an email opt in page that can load as fast as possible.

At the moment, it takes a second to load my Facebook Pixel and Google analytics which make the page a bit slower.

I need the tracking on all other pages, but I'd rather have this one page load as fast as possible without tracking.

What would be the best way for me to do this? Can I exclude all tracking from just this one page someone without having to remove it from the rest of the site?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://kinsta.com/blog/disable-wordpress-plugins/)?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your pixel & analytics code in a test for that particular page using `is_page()`, for example:

```
if ( !is_page( 'email-opt-in' ) { 
    echo "<!-- code here -->";
}
```

`is_page()` can accept the page ID or the page slug. See [Codex page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/).

Comment: I'm using a theme that has me install the pixel and analytics across the entire site in a designated area. 

Do you mean I can take this, place it inside that theme area, and so long as I have the pixel and analytics within this if statement, they will not load on the page? 

Thanks for this!

Comment: _No, you can't do that._ You would need to not use those theme fields and instead add _all_ of the code that Facebook and Google supply to your theme's header. This would go in the `header.php` file, but you shouldn't ever edit the theme's copy of that file, rather a copy of it installed in a Child theme. Or you could create your own plugin to hook into the `wp_head()` function.

Comment: This sounds like what I need but its a little over my head. Any chance you could point me in the right direction as to how I can create a plugin or child theme like this?